# Previous instance of table appends to the newly invoked table. The page should show only one table

Tags: java, user-interface, jtable

When I click the button called Enrolled Subjects, a table showing enrolled subjects is invoked. The data is loaded from a text file. But when I go to another page of the application and go back to the Enrolled Subjects or when I click the Enrolled Subjects Button again, a new table loads and adds to the previously loaded table. This makes the table grow longer every time I click Enrolled Subjects. I have added a removeAll() method which clears the content of the pane before loading the table again, but the previously loaded table, for some reason, does not go away.

Here's the code of the panel where the table is attached.

```
  public class EnrolledSubjectsPanel extends JPanel
    {
        public EnrolledSubjectsPanel(String path)
        {

            setBackground(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
            setBounds(183, 280, 1129, 401);
            setLayout(null);

            LoadTable table = new LoadTable(path);
            table.setBounds(0,60,1129,600);
            add(table);

            JLabel lblEnrolledSubjects = new JLabel("Enrolled Subjects");
            lblEnrolledSubjects.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 35));
            lblEnrolledSubjects.setBounds(446, 0, 292, 43);
            add(lblEnrolledSubjects);
            setVisible(true);
        }
    }
```

The class that creates the table

```
    public class LoadTable extends JPanel
    {
        private static String path;
        private static  String header[] = {"Subject", "Schedule", "Room", "Proferssor", "Units"};
        private static  DefaultTableModel dtm = new DefaultTableModel(null, header);
        boolean isLaunched;
        public LoadTable(String path)
        {
            this.path = "subjects" + path;

            setBackground(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
            setBounds(183, 280, 1129, 401);
            setLayout(null);

            JTable table = new JTable(dtm);
            JScrollPane jsp = new JScrollPane(table);
            jsp.setBounds(0, 0, 1129, 380); 
            add(jsp);

            try
            {
            TextReaderBasic file = new TextReaderBasic(path);
            String data[] = file.openFile();
            int i = 0;
            for(i = 0; i <= data.length; i++)
            {

                addRow(i);
            }

            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            }
            setVisible(true);
        }

        public static void addRow(int x)
        {   
            try
            {       
            TextReaderBasic file = new TextReaderBasic(path);
            String data[] = file.openFile();
            int size = data.length;
            int i = 0 + x;
            int j = 6 + x;
            int k = 12 + x;
            int l = 18 + x;
            int m = 24 + x;

            dtm.addRow(new Object[]{data[i], data[j], data[k], data[l], data[m]});
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                System.out.println("Action completed :)");
            }       
        }
    }
```

The main class where the panel is attached to

```
public class LaunchPage extends JFrame
{   public LaunchPage(String path) 
    {
        getContentPane().setBackground(Color.white);
        getContentPane().setLayout(null);

        StudentBasicInformationPanel studentBasicInfo = new StudentBasicInformationPanel(path);
        getContentPane().add(studentBasicInfo);

        JLabel universityTitleL = new JLabel("Evil Genuises University");
        universityTitleL.setFont(new Font("Edwardian Script ITC", Font.ITALIC, 42));
        universityTitleL.setBounds(514, 11, 343, 65);
        getContentPane().add(universityTitleL);

        JPanel panelToAttach = new JPanel();
        panelToAttach.setBounds(173, 280, 1129, 404);
        getContentPane().add(panelToAttach);
        setSize(1366, 768);

        JButton enrollmentButton = new JButton("Enrollment");
        enrollmentButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) 
            {
            panelToAttach.removeAll();

            EnrollmentPanel ep = new EnrollmentPanel();
            ep.setBackground(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
            ep.setBounds(0, 0, 1129, 401);
            panelToAttach.add(ep);
            repaint();
            }
        });
        enrollmentButton.setBounds(10, 280, 157, 58);
        getContentPane().add(enrollmentButton);

        JButton viewEnrolledSubjectsButton = new JButton("Enrolled Subjects");
        viewEnrolledSubjectsButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) 
            {
                panelToAttach.removeAll();
                EnrolledSubjectsPanel es = new EnrolledSubjectsPanel(path);
                es.setBackground(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
                es.setBounds(0, 0, 1129, 401);
                panelToAttach.add(es);  
                repaint();
            }
        });
        viewEnrolledSubjectsButton.setBounds(10, 349, 157, 58);
        getContentPane().add(viewEnrolledSubjectsButton);

        JButton viewGradesButton = new JButton("View Grades");
        viewGradesButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0)
            {
                panelToAttach.removeAll();
                GradesPanel gp = new GradesPanel();
                gp.setBackground(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
                gp.setBounds(0, 0, 1129, 401);
                panelToAttach.add(gp);
                repaint();
            }
        });
        viewGradesButton.setBounds(10, 418, 157, 58);
        getContentPane().add(viewGradesButton);

        JButton clearanceButton = new JButton("Clearance");
        clearanceButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) 
            {
                panelToAttach.removeAll();
                ClearancePanel cp = new ClearancePanel();
                cp.setBackground(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
                cp.setBounds(0, 0, 1129, 401);
                panelToAttach.add(cp);
                repaint();
            }
        });
        clearanceButton.setBounds(10, 487, 157, 58);
        getContentPane().add(clearanceButton);

        JButton viewAccountButton = new JButton("View Account");
        viewAccountButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) 
            {
                panelToAttach.removeAll();
                AccountPanel ap = new AccountPanel();
                ap.setBackground(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
                ap.setBounds(0, 0, 1129, 401);
                panelToAttach.add(ap);
                repaint();
            }
        });
        viewAccountButton.setBounds(10, 556, 157, 58);
        getContentPane().add(viewAccountButton);

        JButton closeButton = new JButton("Close");
        closeButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() 
        {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
            {
                System.exit(0);
            }
        });

        closeButton.setBounds(10, 626, 157, 58);
        getContentPane().add(closeButton);

        setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Try using below code in your `LoadTable` class before you adding the rows to the table. It will clear the rows in the table model.

```
 dtm.setRowCount(0);
```

So your new `LoadTable` class should look like this:

```
public class LoadTable extends JPanel
{
    private static String path;
    private static  String header[] = {"Subject", "Schedule", "Room", "Proferssor", "Units"};
    private static  DefaultTableModel dtm = new DefaultTableModel(null, header);
    dtm.setRowCount(0);  //THIS WILL CLEAR THE ROWS IN YOUR STATIC TABLEMODEL
    boolean isLaunched;
    public LoadTable(String path)
    {
        this.path = "subjects" + path;

        setBackground(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
        setBounds(183, 280, 1129, 401);
        setLayout(null);

        JTable table = new JTable(dtm);
        JScrollPane jsp = new JScrollPane(table);
        jsp.setBounds(0, 0, 1129, 380); 
        add(jsp);

        try
        {
        TextReaderBasic file = new TextReaderBasic(path);
        String data[] = file.openFile();
        int i = 0;
        for(i = 0; i <= data.length; i++)
        {

            addRow(i);
        }

        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
        setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void addRow(int x)
    {   
        try
        {       
        TextReaderBasic file = new TextReaderBasic(path);
        String data[] = file.openFile();
        int size = data.length;
        int i = 0 + x;
        int j = 6 + x;
        int k = 12 + x;
        int l = 18 + x;
        int m = 24 + x;

        dtm.addRow(new Object[]{data[i], data[j], data[k], data[l], data[m]});
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println("Action completed :)");
        }       
    }
}
```

Comment: Oh my. That did it! Thanks a lot. I didn't know the fix was that easy.